# How to get NA using xpathApply if node doesnot exist in XML files in R?

Tags: xml, r

Here the problem is some XML files do not includes some nodes in some instances, like "year" node in the example code. `xpathApply` will ignore it directly, however, I'd want to get the `xmlValue` together with `NA` with the original order. It looks like this is not similar with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459611/return-blank-if-the-node-does-not-exist-in-xml-using-r).

```
xml_string = c(
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>',
'<movies>',
'<movie mins="126" lang="eng">',
'<title>Good Will Hunting</title>',
'<director>',
'<first_name>Gus</first_name>',
'<last_name>Van Sant</last_name>',
'</director>',
'<year>1998</year>',
'<genre>drama</genre>',
'</movie>',
'<movie mins="106" lang="spa">',
'<title>Y tu mama tambien</title>',
'<director>',
'<first_name>Alfonso</first_name>',
'<last_name>Cuaron</last_name>',
'</director>',
'<genre>drama</genre>',
'</movie>',
'<movie mins="106" lang="spa">',
'<title>ABC</title>',
'<director>',
'<first_name>Alfonso</first_name>',
'<last_name>Cuaron</last_name>',
'</director>',
'<year>2001</year>',
'<genre>drama</genre>',
'</movie>',
'</movies>')

library(XML)
movies_xml = xmlParse(xml_string, asText = TRUE)
unlist(xpathApply(movies_xml, "//year", xmlValue))
```

The result is:

```
[1] "1998" "2001"
```

how to get quickly:

```
"1998" NA "2001"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an XPath `boolean` test per-parent node:

```
xpathSApply(movies_xml, "//movies/movie", function(x) {
  if (xpathSApply(x, "boolean(./year)")) {
    xpathSApply(x, "./year", xmlValue)
  } else {
    NA
  }
})

## [1] "1998" NA     "2001"
```

For those using `xml2`, here's how to do it there:

```
library(xml2)

doc <- read_xml(paste0(xml_string, collapse="\n"))
movies <- xml_find_all(doc, "//movies/movie")
sapply(movies, function(x) {
  tryCatch(xml_text(xml_find_one(x, "./year")),
           error=function(err) NA)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function to replace missing nodes with NA and collapse multiple nodes.

```
xmlGetValue <- function(x, node){
  a <- xpathSApply(x, node, xmlValue)
  ifelse(length(a) == 0, NA, 
   ifelse(length(a) > 1, paste(a, collapse=", "), a))
}

xpathSApply(movies_xml, "//movie", xmlGetValue, "./year")
[1] "1998" NA     "2001"
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider passing the xml string into a dataframe by movie node and create a list from the year column:

```
movies_xml = xmlParse(xml_string, asText = TRUE)
xmldf <-xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(movies_xml, "//movie"))
yearlist <- c(xmldf[3])
```

Output

```
$year
[1] "1998" NA     "2001"
```